# How do we find the final temperature of a system undergoing an adiabatic change?

Tags: thermodynamics

When one mole of a monoatomic ideal gas at 'T' (in Kelvin) undergoes adiabatic change under the constant external pressure of 1 atm, changes volume from 1 liter to 2 liters. The final temperature in Kelvin would be (in terms of 'T')?

I've tried using the Adiabatic equation: PV^(gamma) = Const. for gamma = Cp/Cv. And got T(final) = T/(2^(2/3)) . But the answer I've read from some sources gives the answer as T(final) = T - 2/(3 * 0.0821) using the formula Delta(W) = nR(T final - T)/(gamma - 1), I'm not sure which formula to use, because the final temperatures are definitely not equal, but both the formulae aren't wrong either. Please help!

Comment: By the way, you may want to look into [mathjax formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). Your equations are hard to read as written.

Comment: It is not easy to read your formula. Is it right if I understood it like that ? $\pu{T_f = T - \frac{2}{3·0.0821}}$. This seems an impossible formula because of the unit problem : $0.0821$ is expressed in liter atmosphere par mol and per Kelvin. Well dividing $2$ by this does not give a result in $\pu{K^{-1}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you tried to use is for an adiabatic *reversible* process, and this process is irreversible.

Here are some "leading questions" to help you solve this problem:  For beginners, you know the initial pressure, the initial volume, and the number of moles.  From the ideal gas law, what does this give you for the value of "T", the initial temperature?  For an adiabatic process (Q=0), what does the 1st law of thermodynamics tell you about the relationship between the change in internal energy $\Delta U$ and the work W?  In terms of the number of moles n, the heat capacity at constant volume $C_v$, and the temperature change $\Delta T$, what is the change in internal energy $\Delta U$ for an ideal gas?